# Check if string contains a regex & no js

Tags: javascript, regex, pac

I have a string and I need to make sure that it contains only a regular expression and no javascript because I'm creating a new script with the string so a javascript snippet would be a security risk.

Exact scenario:

1. JS in mozilla addon loads configuration as json through HTTPrequest (json contains {"something": "^(?:http|https)://(?:.*)"}
2. JS creates a pac file(proxy configuration script) that uses the "something" regex from the configuration

Any ideas how to escape the string without destroying the regex in it?

Comment: Regexes aren't regular. I doubt it will be possible to match a regex with a regex accurately.

Comment: So, the string is read/converted from a file? That means you can't separate regex constructs from anything else.

Comment: As stated above the string is from a json file loaded through a httprequest. But because of security concerns from Mozilla (makes also sense to me) I need to make sure that the string really contains a regex and nothing else. If it would contain javascript instead of the regex, the js would be executed in the pac file.

Comment: So what's first, the string or the json file? When and how could JS be executed?

Comment: The json file is the source of the string! The JS could be executed because I generate a new pac-script (proxy config) inside my script with the string.

Comment: Your best bet is to cull the string to the regex part. Whether that is a key/value pair I don't know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that *most of the standard JavaScript functionality is available* ([source](http://www.proxypacfiles.com/proxypac/static/netscape-proxy-format.html)), so you can just do:

```
try {
    RegExp(json.something+'');
    pacFile += 'RegExp(' + JSON.stringify(json.something+'') + ')';
} catch(e) {/*handle invalid regexp*/}
```

And not worry, because a `RegExp("console.log('test')")` will only produce a valid `/console.log('test')/` regexp and execute nothing.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regular expression to pull apart a JavaScript regular expression.

Then you should convert the regex to a lexically simpler subset of JavaScript that avoids all the non-context-free weirdness about what `/` means, and any irregularities in the input regex.

```
var REGEXP_PARTS = "(?:"
    // A regular character
    + "[^/\r\n\u2028\u2029\\[\\\\]"
    // An escaped character, charset reference or backreference
    + "|\\\\[^\r\n\u2028\u2029]"
    // A character set
    + "|\\[(?!\\])(?:[^\\]\\\\]|\\\\[^\r\n\u2028\u2029])+\\]"
    + ")";

var REGEXP_REGEXP = new RegExp(
    // A regex starts with a slash
    "^[/]"
    // It cannot be lexically ambiguous with a line or block comemnt
    + "(?![*/])"
    // Capture the body in group 1
    + "(" + REGEXP_PARTS + "+)"
    // The body is terminated by a slash
    + "[/]"
    // Capture the flags in group 2
    + "([gmi]{0,3})$");

 var match = myString.match(REGEXP_REGEXP);

 if (match) {
   var ctorExpression =
       "(new RegExp("
         // JSON.stringify escapes special chars in the body, so will
         // preserve token boundaries.
         + JSON.stringify(match[1])
         + "," + JSON.stringify(match[2])
       + "))";
   alert(ctorExpression);
 }
```

which will result in an expression that is in a well-understood subset of JavaScript.

The complex regex above is not in the [TCB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trusted_computing_base).  The only part that needs to function correctly for security to hold is the `ctorExpression` including the use of `JSON.stringify`.